# Convert a string to Hex in VB

Tags: string, hex

In VB, I'm reading a file line by line using IO.File.Readline() Method. Each line of the file contains a string similar to the following

":1A2C003F4EDCFE3A2F5D66\r\n"

Now for each line I read, All I want to do is 
1. Remove the ":" and "\r\n" from the line
2. pair the values as bytes e.g:"1A 2C 00"... (Now the line would be "1A 2C 00 3F 4E DC FE 3A 2F 5D 66")
3. Add all the bytes together and to find the result is zero or not. e.g: (1A+2C+00+3F+4E+DC+FE+3A+2F+5D+66)=0?

How can I proceed?

So far I have done

```
While endofstream = False
    stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    If stringReader.StartsWith(":") Then
        stringReader = stringReader.Replace(vbCr, "")
        stringReader = stringReader.Replace(":", "")

    MsgBox(stringReader)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please share that code.

Comment: So far I'm able to read the file line by line and I could check whether the line 'if line.startswith (":")' and then to eliminate ":" and "\r\n" from the line. That's all I could do.

Comment: While endofstream = False
                stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
                If stringReader.StartsWith(":") Then
                    stringReader = stringReader.Replace(vbCr, "")
                    stringReader = stringReader.Replace(":", "")
                    MsgBox(stringReader)

Comment: No no, edit the question and paste it there.. so it's readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But be careful. Shouldn't you have parts of 4 characters? 1A2C 003F 4EDC ...

All you have to do is to convert hex to decimal numbers and sum them

```vb
Dim sum As Integer
For index As Integer = 0 To stringReader .Length-1 Step 2
    ' we take 2 chars
    ' we use ToInt32 method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1cbtwff.aspx
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(stringReader.Chars(index) & stringReader.Chars(index+1), 16)
Next

' use sum
```

In my case, the result is 985